# anyLogic root.?<PMLSettings>.i: Trying to schedule an event in the past. Negative timeout: -0.2926010883311392

Tags: anylogic

when I run my model, sometimes the follow error occurred, it seems "Hold" process its unblock() methods
cause this.

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
root.?<PMLSettings>.i: Trying to schedule an event in the past. Negative timeout: -0.2926010883311392
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.?<PMLSettings>.i: Trying to schedule an event in the past. Negative timeout: -0.2926010883311392
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.EventOriginator.m(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.DynamicEvent.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$i.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler.m(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler.m(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler.c(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler.m(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler.addEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.notifyReady(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.take(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.stopDelay(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.MoveTo$a.onArrival(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.ca.m(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.ca$m.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.f(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.fn(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$i.run(Unknown Source)
```

i try to set "Delay" sleep more times,but not help[anylogic](/questions/tagged/anylogic)

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your model? So that we can see what blocks you have and what the connection between them?
Do you have a schedule model? If so, please also add the picture of its settings.

Comment: Do you have a probability distribution set as a delay value somewhere? If it doesn't have a defined minimum, then there's a non-zero chance it will give back a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple and the error is telling you what you are doing wrong... You have something in your model (and it's not possible to see what it is through the error) that has a negative timeout

AnyLogic has many events happening all the time (events, dynamic events, transitions, etc) and each one of them requires a defined amount of time to be triggered.

We often use variables or functions to calculate what that timeout should be, and in your case, the calculation of that time turns out to be a negative value. You need to discover that on your own though since you don't give us enough information to tell you what it is.